# AEM 6.3 Different template of the same page for each audience (target)

Tags: aem, aem-6

**Is it possible to have different templates of the same page for each audience/target?**

This is the scenario:

Suppose I have the following audience/targets: Users, Super Users and Default.

Say I want to see my index page showing a different template depending on the audience/current logged in user.

Is this possible? How would you accomplish it?

If this is not possible using templates, is there another way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: template is not at all referred while rendering the page. you will have to put your logic in the page component (or other components).

Comment: Got it! It seems I'm confusing the template's purpose. Thanks!